# max-width doesn't work in flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to get a two-column flexbox with some content on the left, and the remaining space taken up by an image. The image should be centred in the remaining space and *shrink-to-fit*. Here's what I've got:

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.small_margin {
    margin: 5px;
}
.small_padding {
    padding: 5px;
}

.red {
    background: #faa;
}
.blue {
    background: #aaf;
}
.green {
    background: #afa;
}

.small_container {
    width: 500px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.large_container {
    width: 900px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.image {
    max-width: 100%; /* Why does this not work? If you change it to a fixed value (not a percentage) it works. */
    max-height: 20em;
}

.image_holder {
    flex-grow: 1;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="red large_container">
    <div class="blue small_margin small_padding" style="width: 120px;">
        <h1>This Works</h1>
        <p>This is what I want when there is space for the full-size image (restricted to its max-height). It should be centred in the div to the right.</p>
        <p>This is good.</p>             
    </div>
    <div class="green small_margin image_holder">
        <img class="image" src="http://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.jpg"/>
    </div>
</div>

<br>

<div class="red small_container">
    <div class="blue small_margin small_padding">
        <h1>This Doesn't</h1>
        <p>There is now no longer space for the image but instead of reducing its size to 100% of its parent div it just overflows.</p>              
    </div>
    <div class="green small_margin image_holder">
        <img class="image" src="http://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.jpg"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, the image overflows the flexbox and isn't shrunk-to-fit by the `max-width: 100%`. Presumably `100%` doesn't actually mean "100% the width of the parent `div`"?

Anyway, is there any way to make this work?

Comment: As far as I know there is **no** CSS solution to maintain aspect ratio a flexible div *and* shrink-to-fit [SO Search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcss%5Dimage+aspect+ratio) . That, I believe, requires JS. Other than that, this is as close as I can get. - http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/VLNajW

Comment: The first column should have `style="width: 120px;"` in both samples? In other words, is the first column fixed?

Comment: The first column isn't fixed; I just made it smaller than its natural size in the first example so you can see that the image div is correctly centred in its parent div.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The image has `max-width: 100%`. That means that it shouldn't be wider than its parent (the flex item). And this works.

Instead, the problem is that the flex item overflows the flex container. That happens because Flexbox introduces `auto` as the initial value of `min-width`. When `overflow` is `visible`, that `auto` forces the flex item to grow so that its content doesn't overflow.

Therefore, you can use `min-width: 0`.

```css
.image_holder {
  min-width: 0;
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.small_margin {
  margin: 5px;
}
.small_padding {
  padding: 5px;
}
.red {
  background: #faa;
}
.blue {
  background: #aaf;
}
.green {
  background: #afa;
}
.small_container {
  width: 500px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.large_container {
  width: 900px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.image {
  max-width: 100%; /* Why does this not work? If you change it to a fixed value (not a percentage) it works. */
  max-height: 20em;
}
.image_holder {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="red large_container">
  <div class="blue small_margin small_padding" style="width: 120px;">
    <h1>This Works</h1>
    <p>This is what I want when there is space for the full-size image (restricted to its max-height). It should be centred in the div to the right.</p>
    <p>This is good.</p>             
  </div>
  <div class="green small_margin image_holder">
    <img class="image" src="http://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.jpg"/>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="red small_container">
  <div class="blue small_margin small_padding">
    <h1>This Doesn't</h1>
    <p>There is now no longer space for the image but instead of reducing its size to 100% of its parent div it just overflows.</p>              
  </div>
  <div class="green small_margin image_holder">
    <img class="image" src="http://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.jpg"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then the image won't overflow the flex container. However, it won't mantain its aspect ratio.

To fix that, you can use [`object-fit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit):

```css
.image {
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.small_margin {
  margin: 5px;
}
.small_padding {
  padding: 5px;
}
.red {
  background: #faa;
}
.blue {
  background: #aaf;
}
.green {
  background: #afa;
}
.small_container {
  width: 500px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.large_container {
  width: 900px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.image {
  max-width: 100%; /* Why does this not work? If you change it to a fixed value (not a percentage) it works. */
  max-height: 20em;
  object-fit: contain;
}
.image_holder {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="red large_container">
  <div class="blue small_margin small_padding" style="width: 120px;">
    <h1>This Works</h1>
    <p>This is what I want when there is space for the full-size image (restricted to its max-height). It should be centred in the div to the right.</p>
    <p>This is good.</p>             
  </div>
  <div class="green small_margin image_holder">
    <img class="image" src="http://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.jpg"/>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="red small_container">
  <div class="blue small_margin small_padding">
    <h1>This Doesn't</h1>
    <p>There is now no longer space for the image but instead of reducing its size to 100% of its parent div it just overflows.</p>              
  </div>
  <div class="green small_margin image_holder">
    <img class="image" src="http://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.jpg"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "Flexbox introduces `auto` as the initial value of `min-width`" - life saving information, thanks!

Comment: Cannot reproduce overflowing in Chrome 66, Firefox 60, Edge 41. Can reproduce  in Internet Explorer 11, though this solution does not work in this browser.